# How to get list of Virtual Machines in Windows Azure programatically

Tags: c#, azure, virtual-machine, virtual

I'm trying to write an application that lists the status of all the VM's and their statuses (running/not running) on Azure. I can get a list of all the cloud services and their names running using the following code...

```
var x = from h in _computeManagementClient.HostedServices.List() select h;

foreach (var item in x)
{
    //item.Properties.Label is the name of the service
}
```

Is there a similar method that I can use to list the VM's and their statuses? I would prefer to not use the REST API if at all possible.

Comment: If you mean IaaS VMs, yes, there are APIs for that - under the Virtual Machines operation group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By VMs, I assume you mean role instances?

You can get at them through the deployment.

```
var instances = _computeManagementClient.Deployments.GetBySlot(serviceName, DeploymentSlot.Production).RoleInstances;
```

This returns a collection of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.Models.RoleInstance` from which you can get status information etc.

The docs for RoleInstance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.models.roleinstance.aspx

Comment: GetBySlot didn't take one argument, so I had to edit it to look like `GetBySlot(Item.Properties.Label, DeploymentSlot.Production)` and then it worked perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated my answer. If the answer is correct, could you mark it? I need the rep ;o)